# Selenium + Python. How to click on checkbox?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, checkbox, automated-tests, frontend

I have problem that I don't know how to solve. I need to set to TRUE checkbox declared as:

```
<li class="consents">
    <form class="consents__form">
        <div class="checkbox-group">
            <input name="5b51a49046e0fb0001bd7b5e" class="checkbox-group__input" id="5b51a49046e0fb0001bd7b5e-SJ7k5D714Q" type="checkbox" value="false">
            <label class="checkbox-group__label" for="5b51a49046e0fb0001bd7b5e-SJ7k5D714Q">
                 <span>...</span>
                 <span class="checkbox-group__required">*</span>
            </label>
         </div>
         <button class="consents__submit" type="submit">Dalej</button>
    </form>
</li>
```

Because those element are in list I created in python loop that iterates over elements:

```
consents = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('input.checkbox-group__input')
for consent in consents:
    checkbox = consent.find_element_by_css_selector('label.checkbox-group__label::before')
    checkbox.click()
```

But every time I got error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException
```

I tried also use xpath, but the effect was the same :(

Comment: Is visible element when you try to click?

Comment: Do not use `::before` in css selectors. `::before` is pseudo-element - it's not a part of DOM. Try just `label.checkbox-group__label`. Also there is no `input` node in provided HTML sample. Share HTML for `input` also

Comment: @Andersson, Thanks for replay. I tried also without `::before` but still nothing

Comment: Check whether `form` located inside  an `iframe` (e.g. `<iframe>...<form>..</form>...</iframe>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry! My bad! @Andersson had right and also there was a bug in my code. The loop should looks like bellow:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.consents')
consents = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.checkbox-group')
    for consent in consents:
        checkbox = consent.find_element_by_css_selector('label.checkbox-group__label')
        checkbox.click()
```